# Plot values are not being generated by my code using R studio, plotly in R, and 'parcoords'

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly

I'm having trouble with plotly in R and 'parcoords'. I'm trying to plot using colorscale defined by Persona. Persona has values of 1 through 4 and I expect each number to have it's own color. The plot scales fine but there are no lines representing the values for each variable.

**Here is the code**

```
options(viewer=NULL) 

p <- df %>% 
  plot_ly(type = 'parcoords', 
          line = list(color = ~Persona, 
                      colorscale = list(c(0,'red'),c(0.5,'green'),c(1,'blue'),c(1.5,'yellow'))) ,

          dimensions = list(
            list(range = c(15,55),
                 label = 'Rescuer Count', values = ~RescuerCount),
            list(range = c(15,50),
                 label = 'Rescuer Share', values = ~RescuerShare),
            list(range = c(5,95),
                 label = 'Avg Serviced Zip Codes', values = ~AvgServZips),
            list(range = c(10,925),
                 label = 'Avg Number of Rescues', values = ~ AAvgNumofRescues),
            list(range = c(310,16000),
                 label = 'Avg Rescuer Earnings', values = ~ AAEarnings),
            list(range = c(1,55),
                 label = 'Persona Share of Earnings', values = ~ EarnShare),
            list(range = c(30,95),
                 label = ' Login Percentage', values = ~ LoginPrct),
            list(range = c(7,95),
                 label = 'Prct of Login Days W/Offer', values = ~ PrctLoginDaysWO),
            list(range = c(1,5),
                 label = 'Avg Acceptance Rate', values = ~ AvgAcceptRate),
            list(range = c(150,1975),
                 label = 'Annualized Number of Offers', values = ~ ANumofOffers)
          )

)

print(p)
```

**Data Table is here**

```
Persona RescuerCount    RescuerShare    AvgServZips AAvgNumofRescues    AAEarnings  EarnShare   LoginPrct   PrctLoginDaysWO AvgAcceptRate   ANumofOffers
1   16  15  45  389 6706    27  71  91  30  1314
2   13  15  90  915 15805   51  91  94  47  1954
3   30  27  28  147 2429    18  55  86  22  679
4   51  46  6   20  319 4   34  75  13  152
```

[resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys7wl.png)

Please Help

Comment: Can you add your data by using `dput`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting in terms of full code. I'm not familiar with dput function. If you could provide a code change for what you're expecting that would be great.

Comment: The idea of dput is just to have a minimal, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for responding Maximilian. What I'm asking is where i would put it in the existing code.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, just put the output of `dput` instead what you have after 'data table is here'. Thanks!